# How bloc a range of IP with Iptables?

Tags: ip, iptables, server

How can I block a serie of IP with iptables ?
e.g. I want to block all the ip begin with 122.225.109.xx

Is it something simple like this ?
iptables -I INPUT -s 211.119.109.x -j DROP

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the subnet mask:

```
iptables -I INPUT -s 211.119.109.0/255.255.255.0 -j DROP
```